# Multiple predictions

Tags: python, datetime, scikit-learn, prediction

I have a df where I need to predict the dependent variable (numeric) for each day in the next 7 days. The `train` data is like:

```
df.head()
Date                   X1                X2             X3    Y
2004-11-20          453.0               654            989  716   # row 1
2004-11-21          716.0               878            886  605
2004-11-22          605.0               433            775  555
2004-11-23          555.0               453            564  680
2004-11-24          680.0               645            734  713
```

In specific, for date `2004-11-20` in row 1 I need a `Y` predicted value for each day of the next 7 days, not just the present day (variable `Y`), and considering that to predict the 5th day starting at `2004-11-20` I'm not going to have the data available of the next 4 days starting at `2004-11-20`.

I have been thinking with the idea of creating 7 more variables (`"Y+1day"`, `"Y+2day`" and so on) but I will need to create a training df for each day as machine learning techniques only return one variable as output. Is there an easier way?

I'm using skikit-learn library for modeling.

Comment: What library are you using for modeling? (e.g. sklearn, keras, statsmodels)

Comment: I'm using sklearn (post edited)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely can train a model to predict multiple outputs in `sklearn`. And `pandas` is very flexible. In the example below I convert your Date column into a datetime index, then use the `shift` utility to get more Y values.

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Read from stackoverflow artifacts
s = """Date  X1  X2   X3   Y
2004-11-20          453.0               654            989  716  
2004-11-21          716.0               878            886  605
2004-11-22          605.0               433            775  555
2004-11-23          555.0               453            564  680
2004-11-24          680.0               645            734  713"""
text = io.StringIO(s)
df = pd.read_csv(text, sep='\\s+')

# Datetime index
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format="%Y/%m/%d")
df = df.set_index("Date")

# Shifting for Y@Day+N   
df['Y1'] = df.shift(1)['Y'] # One day later
df['Y2'] = df.shift(2)['Y'] # Two...
```

We have to impute or drop the NaNs that result when we use shift. In a large dataset this hopefully only results in imputed or dropped data at the edge of the time range. For example if you want 7 days shifted you would lose 7 days from your dataset depending on how your data are structured and how you need to shift.

```
df.dropna(inplace=True) # Drop two rows

train, test = train_test_split(df)
# Get two training rows
trainX = train.drop(["Y", "Y1", "Y2"], axis=1)
trainY = train.drop(["X1", "X2", "X3"], axis=1)

# Get the test row
X = test.drop(["Y", "Y1", "Y2"], axis=1)
Y = test.drop(["X1", "X2", "X3"], axis=1)
```

Now we can instantiate a classifier from sklearn and do our predictions.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

clf = LinearRegression()
model = clf.fit(trainX, trainY)
model.predict(X) # Array of three numbers
model.score(X, Y) # Predictably abysmal score
```

These all ran just fine for me with sklearn version `0.20.1`. Now of course I got a terrible score result from this, but the model does train, and the predict method does return a prediction for each Y column, and the score method returns a score.